# The sum of two positive integers is 29 , find the minimum value of the sum of their squares.

Tags: optimization, contest-math

If the sum of two positive integers a and b is 29 , find the minimum value of the sum of their squares.

Of course I dont need a brute force answer. What is a quick way to find what a and b is?

Answer (score 2):

Since $29^2=(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$, to make $a^2+b^2$ as small as possible, you want to make $ab$ as large as possible.  You do this by making $a$ and $b$ as close together as possible, so in this case, $a=14$ and $b=15$.  (It is a well-known fact that when the sum of two numbers is fixed, their product gets smaller as you move them apart.  You can prove this by supposing $a\leq b$ and comparing $(a-h)(b+h)=ab-h(b-a)-h^2$ to $ab$ for $h>0$.)

Answer (score 2):

For real $x$ let$f(x)=x^2 +(29-x)^2$.Then $f'(x)=2x-2(29-x)$ and $f''(x)=4$. We have $f'(29/2)=0$ while $f''$ is  always positive.  So (1)... $x>29/2\implies f'(x)>0\implies f(x)$ increases when $x$ increases. And (2)... $x<29/2 \implies f'(x)<0\implies f(x)$ decreases when $x$ increases.  (3)...Therefore to minimize $f$ we want $x$ as close to $29/2$ as possible. So put $x=15,y=29-x=14$ and $x^2+y^2=421.$